# Yii + MongoDB + ActiveRecord. How can I use raw queries in ActiveRecord?

Tags: mongodb, activerecord, yii

I'm newby in MongoDB and Yii framework, but i need to select data from collection of documents that have complicated structure (nested arrays of data). I managed to write query that does it, but i don't know how to insert it into existing code that uses ActiveRecord and QueryTrait.
Here's my query (written using MongoDB syntax):

```
db.getCollection("product").find({"options.values":{"$elemMatch": {"$elemMatch":{"$in":['some_value']}}} })
```

But existing code uses ActiveRecord + QueryTrait to select documents:

```
    $query = new ActiveQuery('product');
    $query->select('_id', 'name');
    $query->andWhere(["_id" => $criteria["id"]]);
    ...etc
```

Is it possible to insert raw MongoDB query in this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably use `Query` instead of `ActiveQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use yii2 official mongodb package

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I didn't managed to insert raw queries in ActiveRecord, but i found how to "translate" them into ActiveRecord language.
So, the query

```
{"options.values":{"$elemMatch": {"$elemMatch":{"$in":['some_value']}}} }
```

is translated like this:

```
            $query->andWhere(
            ['options.values' =>
                ['$elemMatch' =>
                    ['$elemMatch' =>
                        ['$in' => ['value1', 'value2'], ...]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
```